# How to pass a string to my controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action

How can I map the following url...

domain.com/Products/product-name-here

I want to map this to my GetProduct action on my products controller.

Here is what I have in my route.config

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Product",
                url: "product/{id}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "EditProduct",
                url:"Admin/Product/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index"}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name:"ProductPages",
                url:"Products/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Products", action = "GetProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name:"OrderRoute",
                url:"Orders/",
                defaults: new { controller= "Order", action="Index"}
                );
        }
```

And here is my action that I want to map the route to.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetProduct(string pageURL)
        {

            if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageURL))            
                            return View("PageNotFound");


            var product = db.Products.Where(x => x.PageURL == pageURL);

            return View("GetProduct");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:"ProductPages",
    url:"Products/{pageURL}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Products", action = "GetProduct" }
);
```

Important: Your default route should be the last route in your route.config.
In your code its the first one.

EDIT: your actual route "ProductPages" should be removed or edited to avoid conflict with my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't actually call an action:

> ```
> routes.MapRoute(
>                 name:"ProductPages",
>                 url:"Products/{id}",
>                 defaults: new {controller = "Products", action = "GetProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
>             );
> ```

You want to add a route that uses actions like so (notice the action tag):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name:"ProductPages",
                url:"Products/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Products", action = "GetProduct", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```